# STRiSTR not matching data from string

Tags: php

Its strange to me, why `stristr` not matching data? It always print `not found`

```
$data = 'Saturday';

$find = 'sat,sun';

if(stristr($data, $find))
    echo 'found';
else
    echo 'not found';
```

Comment: stristr expect second parameter string you are giving an array

Comment: @SunilPachlangia its string.

Comment: If this is not an array then look at your string how you are expecting it to match

Comment: @SunilPachlangia `Sat` and `sat` should match.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Exactly what made you believe you can give alternatives like `sat` and `sun`in the needle parameter separated by commas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stristr()` find the first occurrence of a string. You can also use `preg_match` instead of `stristr()`.

Try

```
<?php
   $find = "sat,sun";
   $data = 'Sat';

   if (preg_match("/\b".$data."\b/i", $find, $match))
      print "Match found!";
   else
        print "not match";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer suite my requirement most.

Answer (score 3):

The `stristr()` function searches for the first occurrence of a string inside another string. So you need to make the search string different, And for this you need make the `$find` string to an array and loop through it. That how you can get the `sat` and `sun` as different string, and simply use your code to match.

[Online Check](https://3v4l.org/XMN84)

```
$data = 'Saturday';

$find = 'sat,sun';
$find_arr = explode(",", $find);

foreach($find_arr as $find_val){
    if(stristr($data, $find_val))
        echo 'found';
    else
        echo 'not found';
}
```

The result should be for first `found` and for second `not found`.

Answer (score 2):

If you find 'Sat', than it will show result Found.

In your case it will consider the 'sat,sun' to **one word**, so that it will try to find 'sat,sun' in `$data` and the result will display 'Not Found'.

Answer (score 0):

You should use *stripos* instead of *stristr* for best results. The *stripos* function is faster and less memory intensive than *stristr*.

**stripos()** returns FALSE if the needle was not found. So if you just need to know if there are ocurrences, use it as follow:

```
echo stripos($data, 'sat,sun') !== false ? 'found' : 'not found';
```

**Solution code edit from comment request:**

To check if your $data value is sat OR sun, do it in a loop:

```
$data = 'Sunday';

$weekend = 'sat,sun';

$days = explode(',', $weekend);
$index = 0;
$found = false;

while (!$found && isset($days[$index])) {

     $found = (stripos($data,$days[$index]) !== false) ? true : false;
     $index++;
}

echo $found ? 'found' : 'not found';
```

Comment: Your solution still print `not found`.

Comment: I wrote the solution code attending to your request using the stripos instead of stristr

Answer (score -1):

Try this one code

```
$f = 'Saturday';
$data = 'sat,sun';

$find = strtolower(substr($f, 0,3));

$str = stristr($data , $find);

if($str)
    echo 'found';
else
    echo 'not found';
```